# Why is phpunit skipping most of my tests even though their dependency succeeded?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test that looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideSomeStuff
 */
public function testSomething($a, $b, $c)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * @dataProvider provideSomeStuff
 * @depends testSomething
 */
public function testSomethingElse($a, $b, $c)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * @depends testSomething
 */
public function testMoreStuff()
{
    ...
}

// Several more tests with the exact same setup as testMoreStuff
```

Even though `testSomething` succeeds, all the tests that depend on it is skipped. Some notes in the [PHPUnit manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) informs that tests can depend on other tests that use data providers:

> **Note**
>   When a test receives input from both a @dataProvider method and from one or more tests it @depends on, the arguments from the data provider will come before the ones from depended-upon tests.
>
> **Note**
>   When a test depends on a test that uses data providers, the depending test will be executed when the test it depends upon is successful for at least one data set. The result of a test that uses data providers cannot be injected into a depending test.

So I have no CLUE why it just skips all my tests. I've been struggling with this for hours, somebody help me out. [Here's the complete test code](http://pastebin.com/smgAsAHV) in case the issue can't be derived from the above pseudo code

**Screenshot of the test results:**

[image: Test results]

Comment: I tried to provide the test results, but I can't copy from the Terminal ([Just asked why on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/151244/52719))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in phpunit 3.4.5, but fixed in phpunit 3.4.12.

Below is a minimal example, based on the one in the manual. I get the same behaviour as you in *PHPUnit 3.4.5*, but I get 4 passes in *PHPUnit 3.6.11*.
Narrowing it down, the [phpunit 3.4 changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/3.4) says it was fixed in PHPUnit 3.4.12.

```
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

/**
* @dataProvider provider
*/
public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
{
$this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
}


/**
* @depends testAdd
*/
public function testAddAgain()
{
$this->assertEquals(5,3+2);
}

/** */
public function provider()
{
return array(
array(0, 0, 0),
array(0, 1, 1),
array(1, 0, 1),
);
}

}
```

Comment: I'm using PHPUnit 3.6.10 though and I'm still experiencing this behaviour

Comment: (Your screenshot says 3.4.5; I'll assume you mean you've upgraded since then) Do you still get the problem on the minimal example I posted above? That is the complete file, just add a `<?php` at the top, save it as `testdeps.php` and run it with `phpunit testdeps.php` from the same directory.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize I had different versions at work and at home. I'll have to try to run the tests again when I get home. Good thing one of us is paying attention \*thumbs up\*

Answer (score 0):

To have a better idea to why your test be getting skipped you can use `verbose`.

`phpunit --verbose .....`

Answer (score -1):

You must define the dependant methods AFTER the main method.

```
public function testSomething()
{
    $foo = [];
    //test something
    return $foo;
}

/** 
 * @depends testSomething
 */
public function testBar(array $foo)
{
    //more tests 
}
```